# checking integrity of a git repo

Tags: git

After I had a disk which reported a long list of "unrecoverable read errors" while accessing a git repo, I fear that i did some pushes to other repos which maybe forward wrong content to them. BTW non of the git commands did report any error while accessing the repo with commit/push/pull. But after accessing the repo I get always new entrys in `dmesg` with unrecoverable read errors on the disk. So there must be some files effected, but maybe the content is redundant.

I know that:

```
git fsck --full
```

will check the repo, but I want to ask:

Did not reporting any errors ( maybe some dangling commits/blobs are not critical as I read ) mean that the complete repo is in valid state? Especially that not only that references and files are existing, but also the content of all files are valid? What I can't find is that there is something like a checksum to make it possible to verify the full content of all the objects stored in the git database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Did not reporting any errors ( maybe some dangling commits/blobs are not critical as I read ) mean that the complete repo is in valid state?*

Yes. `git fsck --full` (and `--full` is the default) checks all the objects and their connections.

> *Especially that not only that references and files are existing, but
>   also the content of all files are valid? What I can't find is that
>   there is something like a checksum to make it possible to verify the
>   full content of all the objects stored in the git database.*

Git has checksums baked right in.

Everything in Git is an object. Every object has an ID. The IDs are a checksum of the content and connections. If the content or connections change, the ID is no longer valid.

For example, a commit ID is basically a checksum of...

- The contents and permissions of all files (git calls them "blobs") at the point of that commit (which have their own IDs).
- The fields of the commit like author, date, log message, etc...
- The commit IDs of the parent commits.

If any of those change, the ID/checksum is no longer valid. It's an incredibly elegant system.

And if that disk is still giving you errors, you really should replace that disk.

Comment: "you really should replace that disk." Quite clear ;) Simply EOL! But I did not recognized that disk error, because only the access times increases but no error was shown using git. Only dmesg shows problems... but I will throw the disk away, data is much more expensive than a 1TB disk at all :-) Thanks for your answer!